# Transferring ether balance from contract balance to winner,not working

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, ethereumjs

here is my Solidity snippet:

```
function deliverPrizes(address payable winner) public onlyOwner{ 
    winner.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

This is what I wrote on truffle console:

```
dCoders.deployed().then((i)=>{
     return
         i.deliverPrizes.sendTransaction('0xd2Bd7C19D539c2F080f70Db89f6a345f6673Abe6',
         {from:'0xF198c57CEfD8899Fb0759883B2b1Aa041E0dD599'})
})
```

But the transaction is:

```
{ tx: '0xffde0828da8362ed214df1dc75fdcbc279ccdcdbfaf8aa06d7341fc6b98a58a6',
    receipt:
    { 
        transactionHash: '0xffde0828da8362ed214df1dc75fdcbc279ccdcdbfaf8aa06d7341fc6b98a58a6',
        transactionIndex: 0,
        blockHash:   '0x25e86d226fec25db3ed06b2a57943a03931e213d9180e90cfd8ad54e60a84a3f',
        blockNumber: 34,
        from: '0x0d67e3546769b104b67cb719427e9c79b3fb3bcf',
        to: '0xf198c57cefd8899fb0759883b2b1aa041e0dd599',
        gasUsed: 29513,
        cumulativeGasUsed: 29513,
        contractAddress: null,
        logs: [],
        status: true,
        logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000400000000080000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000002000000000000000000000000',
        v: '0x1c',
        r: '0x6b260f24839b98cccf459c20a6f3d5e92ca3208db97ad44370ea9afceb5307da',
        s: '0x6200005b196f2da06d1cc4d2f91447133b7f7a9ac671a9be54c21e635e7bd59c',
        rawLogs: [ [Object] ] 
    },
logs: [] 
}
```

So it is from owner's account to winner's one, not from contract address's one. Also no amount is being deducted from owner's account, since the transaction only includes gas fee.

Comment: I'm confused, in the transaction receipt I see `from: '0x0d67e3546769b104b67cb719427e9c79b3fb3bcf',
        to: '0xf198c57cefd8899fb0759883b2b1aa041e0dd599'`, but from the command you use  `"from:'0xF198c57CEfD8899Fb0759883B2b1Aa041E0dD599'"`. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm also confused with this thing..So i pasted snippets as it is.

Comment: This is a duplicate. Two solid answers over here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/65660/accepting-ether-in-a-smart-contract. Why don't you respond to the people who have tried to help?

Comment: @user9851564 your only argument is `0xd2Bd7C19D539c2F080f70Db89f6a345f6673Abe6`, which is nowhere to be seen in the tx receipt. To ensure this is really the transaction corresponding to your call, find the argument value in tx `input` data.